# Keypress pass-through using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keypress

I am trying to make an event/character pass-through in javascript/jQuery that basically delays the "actuating" of the keypress event by about 2000ms. I've set up a handler to capture all keypress events and put them in a buffer. But I am having trouble "playing back" the sequence of keypresses stored in the buffer.

The way it works (and you will see this in the snippet) is that hitting the **"+"** key starts the buffering. After you hit **"+"**, any keys you hit after that are stored into a buffer. And after 2000ms, the buffering is turned off. If you hit **"Enter"** within 2000ms of hitting **"+"**, then the buffer is emptied (and I'm doing something else there in my real code). But, if you do not hit "Enter" within 2000ms, then the keypresses need to be played back.  And that's where I am having the issue.

When the `keyBuffer` is played back, I want the characters (that should result from triggering a keypress) to appear in whichever input control the user happens to be in (at the cursor). But when I trigger the events, nothing is showing up. I may be doing this completely wrong, but I am not sure. I am also keeping the string of characters that coincide with the `keyBuffer` (stored in `stringBuffer`, in case I can use the string to insert the characters (instead of playing back the keypresses). But the problem there is that I do not know which input control the user might be in.

Is there a way to modify my code (below) so that the keypress events I am programmatically triggering (in my loop) will make the characters show up in the focused input control?

```js
var checkForSwipe = false;
var stringBuffer = '';
var keyBuffer = [];

        $('body').keypress(function (e) {
            var charCode = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode
            if (charCode == 43) { // "+"
                //ENABLE KEY BUFFERING:
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                checkForSwipe = true;
                stringBuffer = '';
                keyBuffer = [];
                //AFTER A SET INTERVAL, IF ENTER HAS NOT BEEN PRESSED, THEN REPLAY THE KEYPRESSES:
                setTimeout(function () {
                    checkForSwipe = false;
                    //REPLAY THE STORED KEYPRESSES:
                    if (keyBuffer && keyBuffer.length) {
                        $('#monitor').append('<b>Enter not pressed. Replaying keypresses:</b><br/>');
                        for (var i in keyBuffer) {
                            var which = keyBuffer[i]
                            var press = jQuery.Event("keypress");
                            press.ctrlKey = false;
                            press.which = which;
                            if (which != 43) {
                                $('#monitor').append(' ' + which + ' ');
                                $("body").trigger(press);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    stringBuffer = '';
                    keyBuffer = [];
                }, 2000);
            }
            if (e.keyCode == 13) { // "Enter"
                if (checkForSwipe) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    checkForSwipe = false;
                    stringBuffer += String.fromCharCode(charCode);
                    keyBuffer.push(e.which);
                    //DO SOMETHING WITH THE stringBuffer...
                    //THEN RESET:
                    stringBuffer = '';
                    keyBuffer = [];
                }
            }
            //IF "+" HAS BEEN PRESSED IN THE INTERVAL, STORE THE KEYS IN THE BUFFER:
            if (checkForSwipe) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                stringBuffer += String.fromCharCode(charCode);
                keyBuffer.push(e.which);
            }
        });
```

```css
#monitor {
  background-color:#222;
  color:#fff;
  min-height:100px;
  max-height:300px;
  overflow:auto;
  padding:4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="i1" />
<input id="i2" />
<input id="i3" />
<input id="i4" />
<input id="i5" />

<div id='monitor'></div>
```

Comment: I am really curious as to why you're trying to do this...

Comment: Card swiper. My client wants to be able to swipe a magnetic card at any given time (even immediately after editing a text box). The cards have a pattern that starts with "+" and ends with the new line (Enter) char.

Comment: In reality, I will set that interval to be around 200ms (instead of 2000ms). I am using 2000ms right now just so it's easier to debug.

Comment: Interesting, okay. Why do you specifically want to "replay" the keypress events, rather than just setting the `input.value` to whatever the `stringBuffer` value is?

Comment: My client may be editing the text box, and the edits might include a "+" character somewhere in the middle of the text box. And if that happens, it will initially trigger the buffering. If "Enter" doesn't get pressed within 2000ms (200ms in reality), I want everything to happen normally, as if buffering was not turned on.

Comment: It's tricky. I'm basically searching for a pattern of keypresses over a very short period of time. If I find that pattern, I don't want the characters to appear in the input boxes. But if I don't find the pattern, I do want the characters to appear in the input boxes.

Comment: @fubar: I'm not getting anything showing up at all in the text box.

Comment: Sorry about that. Is [this one](https://jsbin.com/zubiqemaqo/edit?js,console,output) any better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simply use your string buffer if you take advantage of [activeElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/activeElement). Just need to strip off the leading "+".

You can use selectionStart to identify where in the string you need to insert the text.

```js
var checkForSwipe = false;
var stringBuffer = '';
var keyBuffer = [];

        $('body').keypress(function (e) {
            var charCode = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode
            if (charCode == 43) { // "+"
                //ENABLE KEY BUFFERING:
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                checkForSwipe = true;
                stringBuffer = '';
                keyBuffer = [];
                //AFTER A SET INTERVAL, IF ENTER HAS NOT BEEN PRESSED, THEN REPLAY THE KEYPRESSES:
                setTimeout(function () {
                    checkForSwipe = false;
                    //REPLAY THE STORED KEYPRESSES:
                    if (keyBuffer && keyBuffer.length) {
                        $('#monitor').append('<b>Enter not pressed. Replaying keypresses:</b><br/>');
                        var currentText = document.activeElement.value;
                        var currentIndx = document.activeElement.selectionStart;
                        var newText = currentText.slice(0, currentIndx) + stringBuffer.substr(1) + currentText.slice(currentIndx,currentText.length);
                        document.activeElement.value = newText;
                    }
                    stringBuffer = '';
                    keyBuffer = [];
                }, 2000);
            }
            if (e.keyCode == 13) { // "Enter"
                if (checkForSwipe) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    checkForSwipe = false;
                    stringBuffer += String.fromCharCode(charCode);
                    keyBuffer.push(e.which);
                    //DO SOMETHING WITH THE stringBuffer...
                    //THEN RESET:
                    stringBuffer = '';
                    keyBuffer = [];
                }
            }
            //IF "+" HAS BEEN PRESSED IN THE INTERVAL, STORE THE KEYS IN THE BUFFER:
            if (checkForSwipe) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                stringBuffer += String.fromCharCode(charCode);
                keyBuffer.push(e.which);
            }
        });
```

```css
#monitor {
  background-color:#222;
  color:#fff;
  min-height:100px;
  max-height:300px;
  overflow:auto;
  padding:4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="i1" />
<input id="i2" />
<input id="i3" />
<input id="i4" />
<input id="i5" />

<div id='monitor'></div>
```

Comment: This is close. This might be what I am looking for. However, the cursor may be in the middle of a long text string when "+" is hit. And if that happens, all the other text gets cleared out and replaced with the buffer. The buffer should insert the text where the cursor is. For example, in your code, type "abc" then hit "+", and then immediately type "def". The "abc" you typed first is overwritten by "def". The "def" should be inserted where the cursor is. And the cursor may be at the end, or it may be in the middle somewhere.

Comment: Looks good. I ended up using this. I made a few mods, though. I needed to insert the text at the caret. But this gave me a great start.